# VBA FindNext Misses one occurrence

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to replicate the code for finding all the values in a specific range and writing "here" in a cell next to them, but I have a problem with exiting the loop, it always misses one occurrence.

Can anyone explain the solution to me please?

[image]

```
Sub TestValue()

Dim c As Range
Dim firstAddress As String

With shGCD.Range("U:U")
    
    Set c = .Find("THIS", lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            c.Offset(, 1).Value = "Here"
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While firstAddress <> .FindNext(c).Address
         
    End If

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint (F9) on the `Set c = .Find(...)` instruction, then stepping through line by line (with a limited data set), using F8.

Comment: I did that and the result is still the same..

Comment: Of course the result is the same, breakpoints won't change how execution happens ...the idea is to step through the code line by line and *see* what it's doing that shouldn't be happening, or what it's *not* doing that *should* be happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
 Loop While firstAddress <> .FindNext(c).Address
```

to this:

```
 Loop While firstAddress <> c.Address
```

You have already updated `c`, so you should look at the address of the current `c` and not its successor.

Comment: What you did was set c to the next address and then asked for the c's next address.  This should put you off one record for the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

Recoded for clarity and catching error if no initial find.

```
Sub TestValue()

Dim c As Range
Dim firstAddress As String

   With ActiveSheet.Range("U:U")
    

       Set c = .Find("THIS", lookat:=xlWhole)
       If Not c Is Nothing Then
         firstAddress = c.Address()
       Else
         GoTo ExitNoMatch
       End If
       
       Do While Not c Is Nothing
         c.Offset(, 1).Value = "Here"
         Set c = .FindNext(c)
         If c.Address = firstAddress Then Set c = Nothing
       Loop

   End With

ExitNoMatch:

End Sub 'TestValue
```

HTH

Comment: Oops! Right you are @BigBen. My code does run and works though.